# ajax function outputs a "0" when I use die() at the end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a php page that is making a couple of ajax calls. The first ajax call is made and on success it activates a second ajax function. Each function has die() at the end. No matter what I do, die() keeps outputting a "0" to the screen. I tried commenting the die() out of the first ajax function, but it never processes the ajax request when I do that. The loading gif just keeps spinning. When I comment out the die() in the second function, it outputs "0" twice. I have no clue why it keeps printing that to the screen.

This is the first function.

```
function json_info() {

    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

    // create a new array to store projects
    $projectsArray = array();

    // get values for all three drop-down menus
    $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
    $industry = $_REQUEST['services'];
    $state = $_REQUEST['state'];

    // array of values for earch of the three drop-downs
    $statusAll = array('complete','incomplete');
    $industryAll = array('mining','textile','construction');
    $statesAll = array('sc','tx','wa');

    // set $statusArray dependent on whether or not "all" is selected
    if($status == "all") {
        $statusArray = array( 'key' => 'status', 'value' => $statusAll, 'compare' => 'IN');
    } else {
        $statusArray = array( 'key' => 'status', 'value' => $status, 'compare' => '=');
    }

    if($industry == "all") {
        $industryArray = array( 'key' => 'industry', 'value' => $industryAll, 'compare' => 'IN');
    } else {
        $industryArray = array( 'key' => 'industry', 'value' => $industry, 'compare' => '=');
    }

    if($state == "all") {
        $stateArray = array( 'key' => 'state', 'value' => $statesAll, 'compare' => 'IN');
    } else {
        $stateArray = array( 'key' => 'state', 'value' => $state, 'compare' => '=');
    }


        $pages = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'meta_query'    => array(
                                    'relation'      => 'AND',
                                    $statusArray,
                                    $industryArray,
                                    $stateArray,
                                        array(
                                        'key'       => '_wp_page_template',
                                        'value'     => 'template-individual-project.php',
                                        'compare'   => '='
                                    )
                                )
        );

        // query results by page template
        $my_query = new WP_Query($pages);
        $projectsArray = array();


        if($my_query->have_posts()) : 

                while($my_query->have_posts()) : 
                    $my_query->the_post(); 

                    $image = get_field('project_photo');
                    $image = $image['sizes']['thumbnail'];  

                    $projectsArray[] = array(
                    'title' => get_the_title(),
                    'lat' => get_field('latitude'),
                    'long' => get_field('longitude'),
                    'status' => get_field('status'),
                    'industry' => get_field('industry'),
                    'state' => get_field('state'),
                    'link' => get_permalink(),
                    'photo' => $image,
                    'num' => $paged
                    );  

            endwhile; endif;

            wp_reset_query();

         } // end of isset

         ?>

         <?php

         echo json_encode($projectsArray);

    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
   die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_json_info', 'json_info' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_json_info', 'json_info' );
```

And this is the second function:

```
function json_info2() {

    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    // get values for all three drop-down menus
    $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
    $industry = $_REQUEST['services'];
    $state = $_REQUEST['state']; 

    // array of values for earch of the three drop-downs
    $statusAll = array('complete','incomplete');
    $industryAll = array('mining','textile','construction');
    $statesAll = array('sc','tx','wa');

    // set $statusArray dependent on whether or not "all" is selected
    if($status == "all") {
        $statusArray = array( 'key' => 'status', 'value' => $statusAll, 'compare' => 'IN');
    } else {
        $statusArray = array( 'key' => 'status', 'value' => $status, 'compare' => '=');
    }

    if($industry == "all") {
        $industryArray = array( 'key' => 'industry', 'value' => $industryAll, 'compare' => 'IN');
    } else {
        $industryArray = array( 'key' => 'industry', 'value' => $industry, 'compare' => '=');
    }

    if($state == "all") {
        $stateArray = array( 'key' => 'state', 'value' => $statesAll, 'compare' => 'IN');
    } else {
        $stateArray = array( 'key' => 'state', 'value' => $state, 'compare' => '=');
    }


        $pages = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'meta_query'    => array(
                                    'relation'      => 'AND',
                                    $statusArray,
                                    $industryArray,
                                    $stateArray,    
                                        array(
                                        'key'       => '_wp_page_template',
                                        'value'     => 'template-individual-project.php',
                                        'compare'   => '='
                                    )
                                )
        );

        // query results by page template
        $my_query = new WP_Query($pages);

        if($my_query->have_posts()) : 

                while($my_query->have_posts()) : 
                    $my_query->the_post();  

                    ?>  


                    <li class="group">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>   
                    </li>

                    <?php

            endwhile;endif;

            wp_reset_query();

         } // end of isset

         ?>

         <?php

    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
   die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_json_info2', 'json_info2' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_json_info2', 'json_info2' );
```

And this is the ajax call to both functions:

```
function run_ajax() {
    // Get values from all three dropdown menus
        var state = $('#states').val();
        var markets = $('#markets').val();
        var services = $('#services').val();

        // This does the ajax request
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, 
            data: {
                'action' : 'json_info',
                'state' : state,
                'status' : markets,
                'services' : services
            },
            success:function(data) {
                // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                do_ajax();
            }   /*,
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }*/
        }); // end of ajax call for json_info



        function do_ajax() {
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl, 
                data: {
                    'action' : 'json_info2',
                    'state' : state,
                    'status' : markets,
                    'services' : services
                },
                success:function(moredata) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                    $('#project-list').html( moredata );
                    $('#project-list').fadeIn();
                }/*,
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    var errorMsg = "No results match your criteria";
                    $('#project-list').html(errorMsg);
                }*/
            }); // end of ajax call
        } // end of function do_ajax
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong that is causing the "0" to print to the screen.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `die()` in wordpress, but [**wp_die**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die)

Comment: You should try and only post the code necessary to reproduce your issue, rather than dumping your entire source into the question.

Comment: @adeneo I tried changing to wp_die, but it still produced the 0. And jsve, I tried to reduce the code as much as I could, but I was concerned I might be leaving something out that could be causing the problem.

Comment: `console.log(ajaxurl);` and see what the value is, im guessing since you dont mention if the functions return the json?

Comment: @David where does console.log(ajaxurl); go? Does it go in the success of the ajax function? I tried it there at it just returned the url: http://mydomainname.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php.

Comment: And the first function does return json, as it returns: echo json_encode($projectsArray);  

The second function returns the actual html that lists the results on the page

Comment: Check this out and see if it solves your problem: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/always-a-zero-after-an-ajax-response

Comment: hmm something up here. That is the correct url and since there is json being returned. try removing the php within the function and just have something like `echo 'success1'; exit();` .....actually i might see it, you are calling `the_title()` in your function which may output 0 for false. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

Comment: It ended up being a third function that was missing die().

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that I'm an idiot, and I was just overlooking the problem. There was a third function called by ajax, and I didn't have die() at the end of it. I was thinking the issue was in my second function since the 0 was showing up in the div where I was printing that content.